# how do we restore kubeflow from backups if the installation is destroyed or how we can back the kubflow as it was if the eks cluster is destroyed

Tags: amazon-eks, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

How am i going to take backup for my kubeflow pipeline and restore it if the installing is failed or the eks cluster is destroyed. i have some finding to get the image of the vanila i am using for database and find out how to take backup and restore but i didnt have any luck so far.

- i have e kubflow running on aws eks cluster
- and i have 15/16 kubeflow pipeline running
- i used vanilla for database
  so now i need yours help to know  how to backup the pipelines
  and restore the kubeflow pipeline if anything happens to the kubeflow
  or eks.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the Kubeflow manifest file, you'll see the list of dependencies it has. The largest one is the database. For those on AWS, you can use RDS as a target for running the database rather than a self-hosted one in Kubernetes.

You can see the instructions for that [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/build-and-deploy-a-scalable-machine-learning-system-on-kubernetes-with-kubeflow-on-aws/).

I used to be the Product Manager for Open Source MLOps at AWS and my team wrong that post.